# buildozer strange errors while apk compile

Tags: android, python, kivy

I cloned my own working app from github. The app using kivy but when I put buildozer android debug deploy I get:

```
t/kiv/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/Makefile
assets/private.mp3: /home/s/py/foodapp/.buildozer/android/app/data/download.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/s/py/foodapp/.buildozer/android/app/data/download.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 491, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 354, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name Food --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.food --private /home/s/py/foodapp/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --permission INTERNET --presplash /home/s/py/foodapp/./data/download.jpg --icon /home/s/py/foodapp/./data/download.png --orientation sensor --window debug
```

Before send to github build was successful, maybe I have to clean some cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to the new sdk release, which breaks some things. We'll hopefully fix that soon, in the mean time you could try the workaround brousch suggests [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/K644j5kZg7A).

Also, if reporting build failures, please run buildozer with the --verbose option (something like `buildozer --verbose android debug`) and paste the *full* output log, not just the last bit. If the above doesn't fix your problem, you should do that here.

General problems that can cause this error include (probably most frequently) missing dependencies. Make sure you have everything, including 32 bit versions if your distro is 64 bit.

Comment: Yes the solution is in your suggested link. I changed buildozer.spec: android.api = 20 and android.ndk = 9d then android packaging done without any erros, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I build successfully on MaC OS X Yosemite. The problem was SDK.

1. Then i followed the instruction to [install full  SDK including Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Then launch eclipse and follow the instruction to install the [SDK packages](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)
3. In your buildozer.spec file, uncomment the line `android.sdk_path =` and add the path to the sdk folder from your install.

With those steps, I can build and deploy to my Sony Xperia Z1 device.